# Fatal error: Class 'Xylyx_MyCheckout_Helper_Data' not found in /home/innersan/public_html/classicfinefoods/app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: php, magento

I got the above error when uploading my Magento Plugin on Siteground. I have tried to deploy this plugin on my **local** system as well as on our **test** system.
 No such errors had arised when deploying on both these systems, but on Siteground it threw this error.

I have developed my Magento Plugin in **Magento Community Version 1.9.1.1**

I have to deploy it somehow on **Siteground** which is using **Magento version 1.7.0.2**

I have also checked about the code compatibility by using version 1.7.0.2 on my local system and then deploying my plugin. Everything worked fine there too.

Here are my required files

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Xylyx_MyCheckout>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </Xylyx_MyCheckout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <mycheckout>
                <class>Xylyx_MyCheckout_Helper</class>
            </mycheckout>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <mycheckout>
                <class>Xylyx_MyCheckout_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>xylyx_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mycheckout>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <mycheckout>
                <class>Xylyx_MyCheckout_Block</class>
            </mycheckout>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

I have also created the proper Helper file named **Data.php** according to the recommended folder locations as suggested in Magento forums.

**Data.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Xylyx MyCheckout Data Helper
 *
 * 
 */
class Xylyx_MyCheckout_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {  
}
```

When I tried to refresh the cache I got this error got **Data.php** file not found

I have checked both my **config.xml** and **system.xml** for any kind of syntactic errors (Be it, white-spaces or any other unwanted tags and checked the tags also)

What could be the actual error happening under the hood??? Or what could be wrong from my side?

Any kind of suggestion on this would be very much help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you used any translations in your system.xml.  If so what is the module name you have given?

Eg: `translate="label" module="mycheckout"`

Have you given the module name as mycheckout?

**Explanation:**

the translate='label' in the system.xml uses the helper abstract class,

```
abstract class Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
   /**
    *   Translate array
    *
    *  @param    array $arr
    *  @return   array
    */
   public function translateArray($arr = array())
   {
       foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
           if (is_array($v)) {
               $v = self::translateArray($v);
           } elseif ($k === 'label') {
               $v = self::__($v);
           }
           $arr[$k] = $v;
       }
       return $arr;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes..you are right. I have used translation in my system.xml and as you have mentioned, the name of my module is "mycheckout". But what effect does it cause when that method inside Helper class is called? I mean can you explain the flow as I am a Java person, and only have few basic knowledge regarding PHP and Magento.

Comment: I mean what should be the next step for this error to get resolved?

Comment: From the information you have provided, the only thing i can see is you are not using your helper class for performing any functions, so the only place a helper class in your module would have been called will have to be for translations.  I guessed that when you said you have a system.xml.   Can you provide more information the system.xml or any other place you have used the translations like email templates etc?

Comment: Hi,If you have not got this error in your local system, look for any thing in the magento folder structure naming conventions, your local development systems might be case insensitive or there could be some other module with name as mycheckout in siteground